# JAXB Unmarshaller - Unexpected element Exception

Tags: java, xml, parsing, jaxb, unmarshalling

I'm using the JAXB parser to convert XML sent via an http request to a Java object while validating it against my XSD schema. The problem is that when the unmarshal() method is called it raises this exception:

> javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element
>   (uri:"http://www.somedomain.com/", local:"assign"). Expected elements
>   are (none)

If I remove the namespace from my root XML element it raises the same exception with the uri portion being empty:

> javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element
>   (uri:"", local:"assign"). Expected elements
>   are (none)

The unmarshalling code:

```
            ServletInputStream xmlFile = request.getInputStream();

            SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
            Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new File("PatientAssignment.xsd"));

            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(AssignType.class);

            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
            unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
            unmarshaller.setEventHandler(new AssignValidationEventHandler(patientResponses));
            assignments = (AssignType) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlFile);
```

My Java class and package-info.java:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "AssignType", namespace = "http://www.somedomain.com/", propOrder = {
    "patient"
})
public class AssignType {
    @XmlElement(namespace = "http://www.somedomain.com/", required = true)
    protected List<PatientAssignType> patient;

    /* Getters and setters ommitted */
}

// package-info.java
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.somedomain.com/", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
```

The XML I'm trying to parse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assign xmlns="http://www.somedomain.com/">
    <patientAssign xmlns="http://www.somedomain.com/">
        <firstName>Buddy</firstName>
        <lastName>Holly</lastName>
        <email></email>
        <dob></dob>
        <phone></phone>
                ...
    </patientAssign>
</assign>
```

If anyone could tell me where I'm going wrong, it'd be much appreciated!

Comment: Add your `PatientAssignType` class to the question please.

Comment: FYI - Since you have specified the namespace and elementFormDefault on the `@XmlSchema` annotation you won't need to specify it in the other places (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need an `@XmlRootElement` annotation on your `AssignType` class.  You'll probably also want to add `name=patientAssign` to your patient instance variable.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by adding "name=patientAssign" to the patient instance variable, but adding the @XMLRootElement annotation made the exception go away. Thank you for getting me out of a pinch!